# read cookie age from http request in server side

Tags: node.js, express, cookies

> ## req.cookies :
>
> When using [cookie-parser](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cookie-parser) middleware, this property is an object that
> contains cookies sent by the request. If the request contains no
> cookies, it defaults to {}.
>
> ```
>      // Cookie: name=tj
>     req.cookies.name
>     // => "tj"
> ```

This is what i found in the [official documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html)  , However, it is expected that `req.cookies.name` returns an object  contains all info about cookie , Not ONLY STRING which is the value of cookie .

#### Expected

```
  req.cookies.name ==> {value:"e3Lfdsd3pd1...er",expiration:...,..:...}
```

### Actual

```
  req.cookies.name ==> "e3Lfdsd3pd1...er"
```

- How to retrieve other info of cookies than its value using `request` object ?
- Is there something ready in `express` or `cookie-parse`, Or have i to use Nodejs built-in API?

Answer (score 2):

You can not access this data because it's simply not there.
The browser sends only the key-value pairs. 
`expires` and `max-age` are local informations for the browser only and will not be  committed to a web server in general.

You can set those attributes on cookie creation on the server, also you can overwrite them later (e.g. for invalidating), but I'm afraid you can't read the values of those attributes.